# Layer 3 routing based on HTTP packet content

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, pf, bsd

I'm running a *HTTP* proxy service and want to route traffic to **various** *Layer 3* *TUNs* based on the **contents** of **HTTP** packets (e.g. *HTTP headers*).

I'm using **BSD** and **Linux** to do this but it doesn't look like either of these are capable of *Layer 7* classification when making routing decisions (at least, without writing my own extensive kernel patches).

So, is it possible to make **Layer 3** *routing decisions* based on the contents of **HTTP** packets in **Linux** or **BSD**?

And, if not, do any **Unix** based *operating sytems* or *distributions* have this capability?

Comment: In short: no. L3 routing can only take IP into consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For BSD i would look into [`relayd(8)`](http://bsd.plumbing) - its native to OpenBSD, but i believe FreeBSD has a port too. It is quite powerful and can do more than a few things (ex., proxy, load balancer, application gateway) including what you are asking.

Read through man pages, particularly the 'Filter Rules' and 'Protocols' section:

- http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/relayd.8
- http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/relayd.conf.5

Definitely jump on the openbsd 'misc' mailing list if you have issues. The community is quick, and the author is often available.

---

`relayd` is intimately connected to the `pf` packet filter, which is how it is able to jointly create rules for Layer 3 and 7

Answer (score 2):

The problem I see here is that you have to accept the TCP connection before you get to see the http request. So even if the system could use application level data it would not have that data at the time it needs to decide where the connection needs to go.

I don't think there is much choice but to have a "reverse proxy" which terminates the TCP connection from the client an then establishes an onward TCP connection to the origin server.